# Form input field not recognized in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have this search form to post using jQuery:

```
<form id="search-article-form" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="LSN71T8CeWr">
    <input id="searcharticle" type="text" placeholder="search..."
        name="searcharticle">
</form>
```

jQuery snippet:

```
$(function () {
  $('#searcharticle').keyup(function() {      
      var form = $('#search-article-form');  
      console.log('form:', form.serialize());

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/search/article/",
          data: form.serialize(),

          success: searchSuccess,
          dataType: 'html'
      });
  });
});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  console.log('data:', data);
  $('#search-results').html(data);
}
```

The problem is that the form does not seem to be serialized properly, so on `keyup` I see only this in the console:

```
form: token=LSN71T8CeWr
```

Also on the server side, the received post parameters is empty.

So wondering what is wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you really posting a seemingly real token?  I'm half tempted to edit that out

Comment: @GeorgeJempty this a (shortened) CSRF token. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing just wanting to be sure, I'd still make it something that doesn't look quite so much like a password might in the wild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine in the attached snippet

```js
$(function () {
  $('#searcharticle').keyup(function() {      
      var form = $('#search-article-form');  
      console.log('form:', form.serialize());

  });
});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  console.log('data:', data);
  $('#search-results').html(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="search-article-form" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="LSN71T8CeWr">
    <input id="searcharticle" type="text" placeholder="search..."
        name="searcharticle">
        
</form>
```

Comment: Right, sorry, I missed the last bit `&searcharticle=ab`