# Cannot convert json to html list using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I'd like to convert a search result received from server to unordered list:

```
function searchSuccess(json, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  console.log('json is:', json);
  var html= "<ul>";
  Object.keys(json).forEach(function(key, val) { 
    html += "<li><a href=\'" + val['slug'] + "\'>" + val['title'] +"</a></li>";    
  });
  html +="</ul>"
  $('#search-results').append(html);
}
```

The json, as I see in the console is like:

```
json is: [{"title":"Hello World","slug":"hello-world"},{"title":"I'm a title","slug":"I-am-title"}]
```

However, instead of the linked `li` , a list of `undefined` is rendered.

What is wrong here? How can I fix it?

Comment: `console.log(key, val)` in your `forEach` and take a look at what they actually are. (`val` here is going to be an index)

Comment: Also it's unclear from your post if `json` is already parsed or if it is still in string format.

Comment: @Taplar the json is received from server. Not sure what you mean at the first comment.

Comment: I mean, literally, the first thing you should do if something isn't working like you expect it to, is to console log the values you are working with and verify that they are what you expect they are.  If they are not, then you have your first step towards figuring out *on your own* what the problem is.  Addendum: and given that the syntax for the callback for `forEach` is `function(element, index)`, trying to do `val[key]` is a quick issue to spot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had an array list with javascript object in your json. These codes works:

- **Little adjustment to your code:**

```js
var json = '[{"title":"Hello World","slug":"hello-world"},{"title":"I\'m a title","slug":"I-am-title"}]';

function searchSuccess(json) {
  console.log('json is:', json);
  var html= "<ul>";
  jsonObject = JSON.parse(json);
  
  jsonObject.forEach(function(searchresult) { 
    html += "<li><a href=\'" + searchresult.slug + "\'>" + searchresult.title +"</a></li>";    
  });
  html +="</ul>"
  $('#search-results').empty().append(html);
}

searchSuccess(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search-results"></div>
```

- **Nicer jQuery way:**

```js
var json = '[{"title":"Hello World","slug":"hello-world"},{"title":"I\'m a title","slug":"I-am-title"}]';

function searchSuccess(json) {
  var $ul = $('<ul>');
  jsonObject = JSON.parse(json);
  
  jsonObject.forEach(function(searchresult) {
    var $li = $('<li>');
    var $a = $('<a>');
    $a.attr('href', searchresult.slug)
    $a.text(searchresult.title);
    $li.append($a);
    $ul.append($li);
  });
  $('#search-results').empty().append($ul);
}

searchSuccess(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search-results"></div>
```

Comment: This fixes `undefined`, but the problem is that it append ANYTHING that comes from the server after each key up. Is there any way to filter out only for the latest searchresult?

Comment: Or if you want to clear the div before appending new you can replace `$('#search-results').append(html)` with `$('#search-results').empty().append(html)`

Comment: Thanks Mark, but this still adds up to results. What I mean is to eliminate the previous (irrelevant) result sets, and show the latest set which matches the search term. The function that sends out values is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56868810 /form-input-field-not-recognized-in-jquery

Comment: Added my answer again, added the `empty()` function to clear the div before appending new content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop and iterate through the json object like so (based on the json you specified being an object instead of a string):

```
var json = [{"title":"Hello World","slug":"hello-world"},{"title":"I\'m a title","slug":"I-am-title"}];

for (var key in json) {
  console.log(json[key]);
  console.log(json[key]['slug']);
  console.log(json[key]['title']);
}
```

You can either specify your json as an object, or parse it from a string to an object like so:

```
jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```